# Не понятна работа функции array_filter

Tags: php

Есть небольшой код:

```
<?php

$str='Один. Два. Три.';
$str=explode('.', $str);
krsort($str); 
$str = array_filter($str);
foreach ($str as $key=>$val){
    echo $val . '.';
    }
?>
```

Если бы не поместили строку в функцию array_filter() , то на выходе бы было `.Три. Два. Один.`
Что в целом делает эта функция в данном примере и почему с помощью её этой точки нет перед первым словом?

Comment: http://ideone.com/OtWtkG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш массив делится не на три части, а на четыре, три точки, три разреза, четыре части. Фильтр убирает пустой элемент.

'[Один].[ Два].[ Три].[]'

очень сильно помогает понять print_r, поставленный в непонятном месте

print_r(explode('.', 'Один. Два. Три.'));

выдает

Array ( [0] => Один [1] => Два [2] => Три [3] => )

четыре элемента массива, без точек

Comment: но точка же не пустой элемент. Но он её убирает. Можете подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: Точка не пустой элемент, точка разделитель.

Comment: '[Один].[ Два].[ Три].[]'
Три точки делят строку на четыре куска, просто последний  кусок у Вас пустой. Но он есть, и ksort его ставит его на первое место,  а фильтр убирает пустой элемент.

Comment: очень сильно помогает понять print_r, поставленный в непонятном месте

print_r(explode('.', 'Один. Два. Три.'));

выдает

Array ( [0] => Один [1] => Два [2] => Три [3] => ) 

четыре элемента массива, без точек

Answer (score 1):

**array_filter** - Фильтрует элементы массива с помощью callback-функции

Если callback-функция не передана, все значения массива array равные FALSE (см. преобразование в булевый тип) будут удалены.

взято с http://php.net/array_filter.

т.е если ключ в массиве пуст, callback функция возвращает false